# Spatial Dependency vs temporal Dependency

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

What is the Difference between Spatial Dependency and temporal Dependency in Deep Learning? If possible please explain with an example.

Comment: Temporal has to do with time frame and spatial has to do with location. So dependency within time frame or within proximity of location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spatial Dependency means a pixel's value is influenced by nearby pixel's value in image. This is because generally they all belong to same color because they are from same object.

Temporal dependency comes in videos.  When a frame changes to next, if there is not a lot of movement in objects, pixel's values remain same. In other words, a pixel's value is influenced by its value in previous frame (time).